# Add dynamically widget in a loop, and get its name, pyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to add a widget in a formLayout with a loop.

In an other function, I want to be able to interact with those widgets, that I have just created.

I tried with a dictionnary. But I have this error: dlg.pushb_freflechis.clicked.connect(recup_fichiers_selec)

NameError: name 'recup_fichiers_selec' is not defined

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QCheckBox
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import glob, os
import sys
import webbrowser
from pathlib import Path


app = QApplication(sys.argv)    # création application
dlg = uic.loadUi("logiciel_Rint3.ui")   # charge l'IHM crée avec Qt Designer


def charger_fichiers():
    # nom_cristal = dlg.lineEdit_cristal.text()
    # date = dlg.lineEdit_date.text()
    nom_cristal = "SiTrans"
    date = "2022-05-06"    
    directory = 'C:/Users/diops/Desktop/Programme Rint_numérique/dépouillement/'+nom_cristal+'/'+date+'/'+'direct'    
    os.chdir(directory)
    # webbrowser.open(directory)
    global L_file_direct    
    L_file_direct = []
    # L_checkb_direct = []
    # input("Enregistrez les fichiers des signaux directs")
    global c_d, var_checkd
    c_d=1
    var_checkd = dict()
    for file in glob.glob("*.tif"):
        globals()[f"checkb_direct{c_d}"] = QCheckBox()
        var_checkd[c_d] = globals()[f"checkb_direct{c_d}"]
        dlg.formLayout_direct.addRow(Path(file).stem, globals()[f"checkb_direct{c_d}"])
        L_file_direct.append(Path(file).stem)
        c_d += 1
    directory = 'C:/Users/diops/Desktop/Programme Rint_numérique/dépouillement/'+nom_cristal+'/'+date+'/'+'reflechi'
    os.chdir(directory)
    # webbrowser.open(directory)
    # L_checkb_reflechi = []
    global L_file_reflechi
    L_file_reflechi = []
    # input("Enregistrez les fichiers des signaux réflechis")
    global c_r,var_checkr
    var_checkr = dict()
    c_r=1
    for file in glob.glob("*.tif"):
        globals()[f"checkb_reflechi{c_r}"] = QCheckBox()
        var_checkr[c_r] = globals()[f"checkb_reflechi{c_r}"]
        dlg.formLayout_reflechi.addRow(Path(file).stem, globals()[f"checkb_reflechi{c_r}"])
        L_file_reflechi.append(Path(file).stem)
        c_r += 1
        
    for i in range (1,c_d):
        checkb = var_checkd[i]
        if dlg.checkb.isTristate():
            print(dlg.L_file_direct[i].text())
    for i in range (1,c_r):
        checkb = var_checkr[i]
        if dlg.checkb.isTristate():
            print(dlg.L_file_reflechi[i].text())
    return


def recup_fichiers_selec():
    for i in range (1,c_d):
        checkb = var_checkd[i]
        if dlg.checkb.isTristate():
            print(dlg.L_file_direct[i].text())
    for i in range (1,c_r):
        checkb = var_checkr[i]
        if dlg.checkb.isTristate():
            print(dlg.L_file_reflechi[i].text())
    return


dlg.pushb_ini.clicked.connect(charger_fichiers)
dlg.pushb_freflechis.clicked.connect(recup_fichiers_selec)
# Execution
dlg.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error. Also, you should *not* use globals. Be aware that a better and cleaner approach with PyQt (or PySide) is by using classes, instead of "functional" patterns, as it allow better access to objects and their attributes (and usually makes code much more readable).

Answer (score 0):

your code is so messy  i can not understand it much! but if you want to create widgets and save them in a dictionary a simple example in pyqt (not ui) is like this which you add objects to dictionary:

```
keys = dict()
for i in range(1, 7):
    keys[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'key_{i}')
    keys[i].clicked.connect(func)
```

and also if you want to get all variables inside class you can use local which i dont recommend it in some cases.

```
for key, value in vars(self).items():
    self.dictionary[key] = value
```

and maybe it is better to write your code using class and it is not really a good practice to use global variables!