Generate buttons programmatically in PyQT
I need to generate buttons within a loop, and inside that loop assign to every button a different task.
I know something like this was already asked, and by doing some search I achieved the following code:
def pressed_0():
    print(0)

def pressed_1():
    print(1)

def pressed_2():
    print(2)

for i in range(0,3):
    setattr(self,f"pressed_{i}", qtw.QPushButton(f"button {i}"))
    exec(f"self.pressed_{i}.clicked.connect(lambda:pressed_{i}())")                
    self.layout().addWidget(getattr(self, f"pressed_{i}"))  

What I don't like a lot is the usage of exec() function and setattr / getattr.
What I ask if if there is a better way to accomplish what I need.

Use a dictionary

why not a list ?

as per @eyllanesc comment see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320664/9877065 Add dynamically widget in a loop, and get its name, pyQt5

is self.layout.addWidget(button) a solution ? so no need otf dict or list ?? see answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/78348030/9877065

As mahkitah wrote in their answer, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using getattr() and setattr(), while exec() should always be avoided. Besides, its usage in your code is completely unnecessary. Signal connections are rarely done with pure functions (the common usage is based on instance members), but in case you actually need to access such functions (and as long as you are really careful with namings), then you should prefer using globals()['someFunction'] for global functions, or locals()['someFunction'] for local ones.

Also note that unless you specifically need access to the names of those buttons (because of hardcoded references or again through getattr()) in a different part of your code, you probably don't need to use setattr() at all: just create a local variable and work with that, as soon as the widget is added to a parent (like you're doing with the layout's addWidget()) you don't need to care about the instance attribute, nor possible garbage collection, because from that moment on the parent has taken ownership of that widget (on the C++ side), and Python won't certainly delete it.

The usage of exec() should be avoided at all times. There's not much wrong with getattr() though.
If you want to get tasks for the buttons dynamically, based on the loop index, there's no way around using getattr.
Here's a working example with an alternative without getattr:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttons = []

        for i in range(3):
            but = QPushButton(f'button {i}')
            func = getattr(self, f'pressed_{i}')
            but.clicked.connect(func)
            layout.addWidget(but)
            self.buttons.append(but)

        # alternative without getattr:
        self.button_tasks = (
            self.pressed_0,
            self.pressed_1,
            self.pressed_2,
        )
        for i, func in enumerate(self.button_tasks):
            but = QPushButton(f'button {i}')
            but.clicked.connect(func)
            layout.addWidget(but)
            self.buttons.append(but)

    @staticmethod
    def pressed_0():
        print(0)

    @staticmethod
    def pressed_1():
        print(1)

    @staticmethod
    def pressed_2():
        print(2)


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()

With the alternative method, the tasks don't have to be named a specific way, and don't even need to be methods of the class.

Why do you use in both the examples the line  self.buttons.append(but)? It doesn't seem to be useful

@Ferex, that's just in case you need access to the buttons later. If you don't you can omit the button list.

Let's say you want to disable button 1, you can do self.buttons[1].setEnabled(False)
